# In SQLite, how to group ranges of values and sort the groups

Tags: sql, sqlite

In SQLite, I have a table with 3 columns: `id`, `value` (integer), and `sort_me`. What I'm trying to query is groups of rows whose `value`s are within +-50 range, and sort everything, within each group and across groups, by `sort_me` ascending. If a group consists of just one member, discard it.

Here is an example table:

```
id, value, sort_me
 1,     1,      15
 2,   102,      22
 3,     3,       7
 4,   101,      13
 5,   312,      53
 6,     6,      34
 7,   309,       3
 8,   104,       9
 9,   521,       8
```

The expected result should be

```
7,5
3,1,6
8,4,2
```

So far I come up with

```
SELECT concat_ws(',', v1.id, group_concat(v2.id ORDER BY v2.sort_me ASC))
    FROM t v1, t v2
    WHERE v1.id < v2.id AND abs(v1.value - v2.value) < 50
    GROUP BY v1.id
    ORDER BY v1.sort_me ASC
```

Which yields

```
3,6
4,8
1,3,6
2,8,4
5,7
```

This is obviously wrong in multiple ways. First, beside the full groups, some sub-groups are also there. Second, the sorting inside `group_concat()` only affects `v2` and `v1` is always appears first. Third, the order across groups are also wrong because `v1.sort_me` may not be the smallest among each group.

Comment: If (id,value)={(1,51),(2,99),(3,149),(4,199),(5,248)} groups (1,2,3) and (4,5)? Or (1,2) and (3,4,5)?

Comment: Good question. For your values, it should be (1,2) and (4,5). 3 is 50 from both side thus belongs to neither. However, if we change the range to be < 60, both (1,2,3), (4,5) and (1,2), (3,4,5) would be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a query myself. Not sure if a simpler solution exists.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM (
    SELECT group_concat(v2_id ORDER BY v2_sort_me ASC)
    FROM (
        SELECT v1.id AS v1_id, v2.id AS v2_id, v1.sort_me AS v1_sort_me, v2.sort_me AS v2_sort_me
        FROM t v1
        JOIN t v2
        ON abs(v1.value - v2.value) < 20
    )
    GROUP BY v1_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ORDER BY v1_sort_me ASC
)
```

Note: The `ORDER BY` clause inside `group_concat()` is only supported since SQLite [3.44.0](https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_44_0).

Comment: Have you taged the wrong DBMS? As far as I know, in SQLite, it is not possible to use an `ORDER BY` clause within `GROUP_Concat`. See https://dbfiddle.uk/05QXDnmS

Comment: Doc: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html. You can see in the chart that `ORDER BY` follows `expr`. And I have it working in my project as well as [SQLite Browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/)

Comment: In your fiddle, the first query is wrong because you can't use `group_concat` without `GROUP BY`. I just tested the second in the DB Browser and works.

Comment: Ah, this feature is added at [3.44.0](https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_44_0). The fiddle uses 3.39.0. I added a note to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm not entirely clear on your question. If I understand correctly, you're looking to categorize values into intervals of 50, such as 1-50, 51-100, 101-150, and so on. After that, you want to group the IDs based on these intervals and sort them according to the "sort_me" column. Beside  concatenating those ids, you want to count the number of ids in each group and discard those with 1 or less. If this is what you are looking for then you may try the following query,

```
WITH Intervals AS (
SELECT 
    id,
    CASE 
        WHEN value BETWEEN 1 AND 50 THEN '1-50'
        WHEN value BETWEEN 51 AND 100 THEN '51-100'
        WHEN value BETWEEN 101 AND 150 THEN '101-150'
        -- Add more intervals as needed
        ELSE 'Unknown'
    END AS value_interval,
    sort_me
FROM 
    your_table
)
SELECT 
    value_interval,
    GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY sort_me) AS grouped_ids,
    COUNT(*) AS num_ids
FROM 
    Intervals
GROUP BY 
    value_interval
HAVING 
    num_ids > 1
ORDER BY 
    value_interval;
```

There is no straight answer for your query as far as I know. Well as I said, I might be interpreting your question wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm not trying to put the values in fixed bucket. Rather, the "buckets" are defined by the values themselves, which is unknown beforehand.

Comment: It seems like the proposed solution will not work for a larger set of values, especially those that are close to each other. Nonetheless, I wish you the best of luck on your journey.